# FFMPEG vertically stack three elements, two images and a box

Tags: ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg I want to stack three elements vertically. The the first two elements are images, while the third is a box I want to draw using the `drawbox` command. Is it possible to do so? What I was able to do was to stack two images vertically and draw a box on the image in the bottom, but this is not what I want.

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## vstack + pad

You can stack with [vstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack) and then add the box with [pad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad):

```
ffmpeg -i image0.jpg -i image1.png -filter_complex "[0][1]vstack=inputs=2,pad=iw:ih+200:color=red" -frames:v 1 output.png
```

## color filter + vstack

You can use the [color filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color) to make a colored box, then stack with [vstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack):

```
ffmpeg -i image0.jpg -i image1.png -filter_complex "color=s=1280x360:color=blue[box];[0][1][box]vstack=inputs=3" -frames:v 1 output.jpg
```

- Each input must have the same width. If they do not then add the scale, pad, or crop filters.
- See [syntax and color names for color options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#color-syntax).